# Swift String initializers?

Tags: swift

I came across these two statements in a Swift teaching book.

1. `let padding = String(count: spaces, repeatedValue: Character(" "))`
2. `println(String(format:"%@%@", "Year", "Test"))`

My questions are:

1. Are both `String(count:repeatedValue:)` and `String(format:)` initializers of
   String?
2. I am not able to find online documentation for `String(format:)`
   Can you please suggest any links?
3. What other initializers of String are available? I can only find `init()`
   and `init(count:repeatedValue)` in Apple documentation

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is structure in Swift. You can get the documentation in Xcode itself.

Here below is details.

> /// Objective-C Bridge /// ================== /// /// `String` is
>   bridged to Objective-C as `NSString`, and a `String` /// that
>   originated in Objective-C may store its characters in an ///
>   `NSString`.  Since any arbitrary subclass of `NSSString` can ///
>   become a `String`, there are no guarantees about representation or ///
>   efficiency in this case.  Since `NSString` is immutable, it is ///
>   just as though the storage was shared by some copy: the first in ///
>   any sequence of mutating operations causes elements to be copied ///
>   into unique, contiguous storage which may cost `O(N)` time and ///
>   space, where `N` is the length of the string representation (or ///
>   more, if the underlying `NSString` is has unusual performance ///
>   characteristics).

```
struct String {
    init()
}
```

Here is a extension for String.

```
extension String {

    /// Construct an instance that is the concatenation of `sz` copies
    /// of `repeatedValue`
    init(count sz: Int, repeatedValue c: Character)

    /// Construct an instance that is the concatenation of `sz` copies
    /// of `Character(repeatedValue)`
    init(count: Int, repeatedValue c: UnicodeScalar)

    /// `true` iff `self` contains no characters.
    var isEmpty: Bool { get }
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you for your response. Please accept my apologies but because of my entry level knowledge, I didn't understand your response. Can you please explain again?

Comment: I will put it this way. Is there any difference between these statements? var    string1 = String("JJJJJ")
var string2 = String(count: 5, repeatedValue: Character("J"))
var string3 = String(format: "%@%@%@%@%@", "J", "J", "J", "J", "J")

Comment: @user3700462, All three will give same same result from your above three string declaration. Bu they have different use in different situation.